# Placement of quotation or epigraph

Tags: positioning, epigraphs

I would like to start a report by juxtaposing two contrasting quotations opposite each other: one left justified on the top-left part of the page, the other right-justified on the top-right part, both starting on the same vertical position, i.e. directly opposite one other.

I'm having terrible difficulty getting this to work, and I haven't been able to find a way to do it with e.g. the epigraph package.

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of what you've tried?

Comment: No, I never managed to even get close. But the solution using parbox, suggested by gernot, works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this effect with ordinary `\parbox`es, their `[t]` option and the commands `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright`, like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright
   The sentence to the right is true.%
}%
\hfill
\parbox[t]{2cm}{\raggedleft
   The sentence to the left is false.%
}
\bigskip

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

> [image]

If you need it more than once, hide it in a new command (adapt `2cm` and `3cm` suitably).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\juxtaposed[2]%
  {\par\noindent
   \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright#1}%
   \hfill
   \parbox[t]{2cm}{\raggedleft#2}%
   \bigskip\par
  }
\begin{document}
\juxtaposed
  {The sentence to the right is true}%
  {The sentence to the left is false.}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```